# How to get the record count of columns matching with particular value using awk command in linux

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have to display the record count of columns matching "CD" from my input csv file. Value CD is appearing in second column in my file input.csv.

I am trying with below command but it is not working as expected.

```
awk -F',' '$2=/CD/ { count++ } END { print count }' input.csv
```

My input data:

```
1234,CD,xyz,abcd
01235,AB,kasdjk,aaaaa,fff
898,CD,laklksas,lsjdjdj,lkjsaj
111,CD,lkakskaks,jjjjjj
3455,00,ksajkjsa,kkkkk
59995,99,asllsal,99898,00,kkk,99
99,00,lkjjjsa,00,99,hhhh
```

Expected output:

```
3 if i check the count of "CD"
2 if i check the count of "00"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator to match with a regexp is `~`, not `=`.

```
awk -F',' '$2 ~ /CD/ { count++ } END { print count }' input.csv
```

If you want to do an exact match, not a regular expression, use `==` and a string:

```
awk -F',' '$2 == "CD" { count++ } END { print count }' input.csv
```

`=` is for assigning, not comparing.

Comment: You could also use /^CD$/

Comment: @MikkelChristiansen You could, but why would you want to? Why use a regexp when it's not really a pattern?

Comment: I was referring to your first awk-line

Comment: I was simply copying the regexp from the question, because the point of that was just to show the correct operator.

Comment: Yes, but the question was kind of a mix between your 2 answers, so the first version should properly be with ^$.